# How to implement access-control for uploaded assets in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, authorization

I have an app with admins and normal users (two separate models). Both can upload files. Currently, the file model does not have an attribute of `uploaded_by` or or any associations with the `Admin`/`User` models. Once a file is uploaded by someone, it's just added to the overall list and everybody sees/can delete everything. I need this:

- admins continue to see/be able to delete everything;
- users can see/are able to delete only their own files, files, uploaded by admins, but not files, uploaded by non-admins;

I would like to ask for advice on how to implement this.

I could add a polymorphic `belongs_to` for files and then do a query like - `File.where(owner: current_user) + File.where(owner_type: 'admin')`.

I am ok with rolling my own system or using something like `punidt` or `cancancan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered your question. Yes, running `punidt` or `cancancan` and adding polymorphic relation are great ways to go. I only can add that your query is much more simple:

```
File.where(owner: current_user)
```

no need to check for `owner_type`.

**More complex model**

On the other hand, I was surprised by simplicity of your model. What if you need to define several rules on a single file. For instance, user1 is an owner of the document, user2 and user3 are editors, and user4 is just a viewer.

In this, more complicated, case you will need a separate model named `UserFileRole` maybe, with `user` (polymorphic), `file` and `role` fields.

Personally I would go with this model, because, just being "admin" still means nothing in terms of the right of editing document. They are two different roles. So they should be defined separately.

Still if your system is really as simple, as you describe, your design is very good.

Comment: Thank you. I think that my query is not that simple, though, because just calling `File.where(owner: current_user)` will only return files, uploaded by the current user, but I want to see those files and also all files, uploaded by admin, but no files uploaded by non-admins.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean.